# PHP and Android Keystore encryption / decryption

Tags: php, android, encryption, keystore

I've been trying to get this for hours now, and I can't find what's wrong. I'm using a php RESTful API that I made to encrypt data using asymmetric encryption.

First, I save my user's public key in the server by exporting it in android:

```
fun exportPublicKey() : String {
        val publicKey = getPublicKey()
        return android.util.Base64.encodeToString(
            publicKey!!.encoded,
            android.util.Base64.NO_WRAP
        )
    }
```

This allows me in the PHP server to do that:

```
$public_key_core = $_POST["public_key"];
$public_key = "-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----\n" . $public_key_core . "\n-----END PUBLIC KEY-----";
```

I am unsure that's the right way but openssl seems to be "ok" with that key ?

I then tested my keystore in local using both keys, and it works just fine using this code:

Encrypt:

```
fun encryptAsymmetricData(data: String, usePrivateKey : Boolean = true): ByteArray {
        val cipher : Cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding")
        val encryptedBytes: ByteArray
        if (usePrivateKey){
            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, getPrivateKey())
            encryptedBytes = cipher.doFinal(data.toByteArray(Charsets.UTF_8))
        } else {
            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, getPublicKey())
            encryptedBytes= cipher.doFinal(data.toByteArray(Charsets.UTF_8))
        }
        return encryptedBytes
    }
```

Decrypt:

```
fun decryptAsymmetricData(data: ByteArray): String{
        val cipher : Cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding")

        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, getPrivateKey())
        return cipher.doFinal(data).toString(Charsets.UTF_8)
    }
```

Using this works because I do ".toByteArray(Charsets.UTF_8)" on the encryptData result.
Now here's the problem, I use base64 encoding and do the following to encrypt in PHP:

```
openssl_public_encrypt($token->token, $encrypted_token, $user->public_key);
openssl_public_encrypt($user->id, $encrypted_id, $user->public_key);
[...]
'encrypted_user_id' => base64_encode($encrypted_id),
'encrypted_token' => base64_encode($encrypted_token)
```

But when I try to decrypt this in Android I'm getting an exception "javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException" caused by this code:

```
val tokenBA = String(getDecoder().decode(this.encryptedToken), Charsets.UTF_8).toByteArray(Charsets.UTF_8)
val userIDBA = String(getDecoder().decode(this.encryptedUserId), Charsets.UTF_8).toByteArray(Charsets.UTF_8)
val token = App.encryptionController.decryptAsymmetricData(tokenBA)
val userID = App.encryptionController.decryptAsymmetricData(userIDBA)
```

(The logic being, I use base64 to send back my data in PHP, so I convert it to UTF8 in Android, then get the associated ByteArray to decrypt it ?)

I know that the encryption works in "local" but it doesn't when using both PHP and KeyStore, so I guess the problem is coming either from the PHP encryption, or from the way I try to decrypt it in android, but I can't seem to find what wrong, could you guys help me there please ?

Thank you by advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, after searching and making sure the issue wasn't the public key stored in the PHP server, I found the answer. It was caused by the way to convert the "base64" string in an actual ByteArray in the App. This worked:

```
val token = App.encryptionController.decryptAsymmetricData(getDecoder().decode(encryptedToken))
val userID = App.encryptionController.decryptAsymmetricData(getDecoder().decode(encryptedUserId))
```

This is only working because I do the "base64_encode" in the server, for some (bad) reason I thought it was needed to go back to UTF8 to get the ByteArray in the app.